# C# How to get the number of the method calls?

Tags: c#

In Java - basing on the Aspects - we can get the number of the function calls, e.g.:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
sc.m1();
sc.m1();
int no = sc.getNumberOfCalls("m1");
System.out.println(no); //2
```

How to do it in C# ?

Comment: If this is just for profiling, I'd recommend taking a peek at the [EQATEC Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/).

Comment: If it's profiling, then dotTrace is business!

Answer (score 2):

this is another option by using external product..In .NET

The canonical, easiest way would probably be to simply use a profiler application. Personally I have good experiences with [jetBrains dotTrace](http://smartbear.com/products/development-tools/performance-profiling/), but there are more out there.

Basically what you do is you let the profiler fire up your app, and it will keep track of all method calls in your code. It will then show you how much time was spent executing those methods, and how many times they are called.

Assuming your reason for wanting to know this is actually performance, I think it's a good idea to look at a profiler. You can try to optimize your code by doing an educated guess to where the bottlenecks are, but if you use a profiler you can actually measure that. And we all know, measure twice, cut once ;-)

or

this is also good option

[AQtime](http://smartbear.com/products/development-tools/performance-profiling/) does that with no difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

I believe theres not suach a built in feature for that, so you may wanna code something this way:

```
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public Int32 MethodCallCount { get; set; }

        public void Method()
        {
            this.MethodCallCount++;
            //Your custom code goes here!
        }
    }
```

If you wanna go deeper you may want look for AOP (aspect oriented programming) interceptors! - if so you may start looking for Spring.NET framework!

If you are within a test scenario the most apropriate solution would be using a mock framework for that.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply do this in your class ?

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private int counter = 0;

    public void m1()
    {
        counter++;
    }

    public int getMethodCalls()
    {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This capability is not built into .NET. However, you can use any one of the mock object frameworks to do this. For example, with [RhinoMocks](http://ayende.com/blog/tags/rhino-mocks) you can set the number of expected number of calls to a method and check it.

You can also accomplish this if you create a [dynamic, runtime proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.tools.applications.dynamicproxy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for your objects and have your proxy keep track. That might make the cure worse than the disease though!

-- Michael

Answer (score 1):

You can also do Aspects in C#.

- [Spring.Net](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html)
- [EOS](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~eos/)